# Meaning of "climate is polite"

Tags: meaning

I want to know about the meaning of 'the Francis University climate is polite'

Please help me; thank you so much.

Comment: I think they meant that general weather around the university is nice, stable and devoid of severe or violent elements

Answer (score 2):

Polite

1Having or showing behaviour that is respectful and considerate of other people:
they thought she was wrong but were too polite to say so.

The definition is from Oxforddicionaries.com. The meaning is that the atmosphere at the university is friendly.

Answer (score 2):

The word "climate" is being used metaphorically here. It does not refer to the weather but to the general nature of interactions among the people at Francis University.  So the meaning of the sentence is just that people at this university generally behave politely.